# What rules does the Catholic Church have for venerating crosses/crucifixes on Good Friday?

Tags: catholicism, cross, veneration, good-friday, crucifix

Each year on the Good Friday service at my parish we venerate the cross, but I really wish it were a crucifix, and I've wondered why we don't have one for that purpose.  I've been trying to find one to just drop off at the church with a note saying "this is better, keep it", but before I do, I would like to know if the  Catholic Church has any restrictions as to what kind of a cross can be venerated during the Good Friday service?

Does the cross have to be a certain size, of a certain material, or are we even allowed to venerate a cross sans-Corpus?

Comment: There is an admirable answer to this question at [TotusTuus](http://www.totustuus.com/friday.htm) which it would seem inelegant simply to reproduce here, even with attribution.

Comment: thanks, kind of a bummer though, probably means the priest is doing it intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

The rubrics for the [pre-1955 *Missale Romanum*](http://garrigou.us.to/get/pdf/Missale%20Romanum_%20Classical%20Form,%20Tridentine%20Rite,%20Old%20Mass%20-%20Catholic%20Church_3453.pdf) (PDF p. 326) seem to assume there is a front and back side of the cross, which could only be possible were there a corpus on it:

> *Completis Orationibus, Sacerdos…accipit a Diacono Crucem jam in Altari præparatam: quam, versa facie ad populum…* etc.
>
> The orations having been completed, the Priest…takes the Cross,
>   already prepared at the altar, from the Deacon: which, [the cross] turned
>   toward the people… *etc.*

It can also be inferred that the cross shouldn't be so big that it can't rest on the altar.